# In all screen, user interface is showing lining and grey color

Tags: android

After update I got this issue. i don't know what is going wrong.

[image]

Comment: Its a long-shot by have you tried calling ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(getApplicationContext());? It's required on older Android. It says it supports TLSV1.2 but it doesn't in reality before you pull in some newer version of SSL.

Comment: That exception appears to be unrelated to SSL.